# Accessing next df ("v+1") while looping over dataframes in dict_values or list

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, iterator, typeerror

I have a dictionary where the values are dataframes. I want to modify dataframe "v" based on a comparison to dataframe "v+1". If I try something like this (all code is illustrative only):

```
for v in dfs_dict.values():
    if v['Date'][0] == v+1['Date'][0]:
        v+1['Day'] = v['Day']
```

then I unsurprisingly get an error. Specifically:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I get essentially the same error if I store these dataframes in a list and loop over that. And, of course, the same error if I flip my approach so that I'm using "v-1" instead.

I've also tried an approach where I turn that list of dataframes into an iterator and use `next()` to access the "v+1" dataframe. I don't get an error when I do this, but it doesn't give me the result (modified df column values) I need either. I don't have much experience with this `iter` approach though, so it may simply be totally inappropriate for what I'm trying to do, but in the interests of completeness:

```
dfs_iter = iter(dataframes)
for i in dfs_iter:
    if i['Date'][0] == (next(dfs_iter)['Date'][0]):
        (next(dfs_iter)['Day']) = i['Day']
```

Does anyone have any pythonic suggestions for how I might achieve my goal? Thanks all.

Comment: How about `for v, vplus1 in zip(dataframes, dataframes[1:])`?

Comment: @j1-lee That's not bad! I wouldn't have thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks complicated. How about this simpler approach?

```
for element in iter(data):
    process(element)
```